# TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request'

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs, jwt, passport-jwt

I am trying to use JwtAuthGuard to distinguish authenticated requests from the unauthenticated ones.

I did follow the [official Nestjs documentation on authentification](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication#implementing-passport-jwt), yet, I can't make it work as I get a typescript error: `TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request'.`

`bookmarks.controller.ts`

```
import { Controller, Get, Req, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common'
import { BookmarksService } from './bookmarks.service'
import { StandardSuccessResponse } from '../utils/standard-response.type'
import { ResponseMessage } from '../utils/response-messages.enum'
import { JwtAuthGuard } from '../auth/guards/jwt-auth.guard'

@Controller('v1/bookmarks')
export class BookmarksController {
  constructor(private bookmarksService: BookmarksService) {}

  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @Get()
  async getAllBookmarkedJobs(
    @Req() request: Request
  ): Promise<StandardSuccessResponse<string[]>> {
    return {
      success: true,
      data: await this.bookmarksService.getAllBookmarkedJobs(
        request.user.candidateId
      ),
      meta: null,
      message: ResponseMessage.BOOKMARKS_RETRIEVED,
    }
  }
}
```

`strategies/jwt.strategy.ts`

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt'
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    })
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return { candidateId: payload.sub }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you don't import Request from express, just add the:

```
import { Request } from 'express';
```

But you needs to have `@types/passport` and `@types/express` installed, and it will works.

Comment: did not work for me, maybe this is outdated...

Answer (score 3):

The `user` property is attached to the `Request` object via `@types/passport`, or by using a custom interface that `extends Request` and adds the type to it yourself, like so:

```js
export interface RequestWithUser extends Request {

  user: UserType;
}
```

Comment: i'm using nestjs where should i add this

Comment: Make it an interface anywhere in your application, and import it when you need the full `Request` type instead of using `Request` from express

Answer (score -1):

You should change @Req() to @Res() since you are getting data.

```
     @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
     @Get()
     async getAllBookmarkedJobs(@Res() res): Promise<StandardSuccessResponse<string[]> {
        return {
          success: true,
          data: await this.bookmarksService.getAllBookmarkedJobs(
           res.user.candidateId
          ),
          meta: null,
          message: ResponseMessage.BOOKMARKS_RETRIEVED,
        }
     }
```

Comment: Using `@Res()` will actually make Nest stop sending the response and require the user to manually take care of it with `res.send()`. It's not advisable to use in Nest unless it's absolutely necessary, and 9 times out of 10 there are other ways to mange the response.